# How to create Navigation Menu Drawer for Android Tv app and its Listeners

Tags: listview, navigation-drawer, android-tv, television

I am Developing Android Tv App and FireStick Tv App. Can any one help me in customizing Home Page by adding Left Menu Drawer with Remote Control Listeners. SideMenu required like HotStar Tv App.

Comment: Did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a side menu similar to Hotstar, then one of the solutions could be `SlidingPaneLayout` and you can use it as per your need. Make sure that side menu contents are focusable to gain focus on TV.